# Negation in natural language

Tags: logic

"In every supermarket, if we can buy fish then the supermarket has a refrigerator"

Is the negation of this sentence

1) There exists a supermarket where we can buy fish and it doesn't have a refrigerator

or

2) There exists a supermarket where if you can buy fish, then the supermarket does not have a refrigerator.

Comment: I would write the first sentence as 'In every supermarket that we can buy fish there is a refrigerator'. The phrase "if we can buy fish" or "that we can buy fish" implies that the supermarket sells fish and at the very least that you have enough money/goods to exchange for the fish.  In that case 'There exists a supermarket that sells fish, that doesn't have a refrigerator' is not a negation of the first sentence. Is that really what you meant to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is correct. 2 is wrong because it is already satisfied if there is a supermarket where you cannot buy fish.

Comment: Thank you. Number 2 I came up with it yesterday, I was also more confident on number 1 but I needed to be reassured.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tell from the words, but translating to predicate logic might make it clearer.

> "In every supermarket, if we can buy fish then the supermarket has a refrigerator"

$ \def\inn{\hspace{1pt}{\in}\hspace{1pt}}\forall s\inn S~(B(s)\to R(s))$

> Is the negation of this sentence 1) or 2)?
>
> > 1) There exists a supermarket where we can buy fish and it doesn't have a refrigerator

$\exists s\inn S~(B(s)\wedge\neg R(s))$

> > 2) There exists a supermarket where if you can buy fish, then the supermarket does not have a refrigerator.

$\exists s\inn S~(B(s)\to\neg R(s))$